# I am New to Python, plotly.plotly is giving error

Tags: python, plotly

I keep getting this error, please help (I have installed plotly too, please find the screenshot): [image: Installation screenshot]

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode,iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

Error is :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5d605d0a202b> in <module>()
----> 1 import plotly
      2 import plotly.plotly as py
      3 import plotly.graph_objs as go
      4 from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode,iplot
      5 init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

ImportError: No module named plotly
```

Comment: `plotly` isn't giving you an error, Python is. Have you installed it with `pip install plotly` (or similar)?

Comment: Ok, I didn't see the screenshot. Are you using Python 3? You might need to use `pip3 install plotly`

Comment: Actually, I also see that the error comes from ipython. In some way, you've not installed `plotly` into the version of python you're using. For example, if you are using Anaconda and haven't set it to be the default system version, then you'll need to install the library into Anaconda separately